# Reflection and Generics

Tags: java, reflection

I am having a bit of a hassle with classes. I must admit I didn't search very well, but the most simple Google search didn't lead me to a proper answer. Since I don't understand why this problem is happening, I thought I would ask for some explanation on it.

I have the following code (or at least the code that's relevant):

```
    public class someClass {
        private final Class<? extends TileGeneric> tileClass;
        public someClass(Class<? extends TileGeneric> clazz) {
           // Some more checks go here, but it's about the class, not this code
           tileClass = clazz;
        }

        public TileGeneric getInstance(World world) {
           if( tileClass != null ) {
               TileGeneric tile = ReflectionUtil.getInstance(tileClass, null, new Object[] {} ); // This method is not relevant, but what you should know is that no compile errors occur here
               if(tile == null)
                   tile = ReflectionUtil.getInstance(tileClass, World.class, world); // Here does a compile occur: (see further details below this code)
           }
           return null;
        }
    }
```

Okay, that is more or less the most important code of my class where the problem lies. The compile error I'm getting is at the second `ReflectionUtil.getInstance` call: `"The method getInstance(Class<? extends T>, Class<?>[], Object...) in the type ReflectionUtil is not applicable for the arguments (Class&lt;capture#9-of ? extends TileGeneric&gt;, Class&lt;World&gt;, World)."`

So the error lies somewhere in what I'm assuming is due to those blocks, but I'm quite unaware if that even is the issue. The very odd thing is that the first call does not error, and that is what really breaks my mind.

If there is already an explanation out there that I couldn't find, please link me to it. I'm very grateful for all help, and really want to know why this is occurring so I can void it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method expects an array of classes, a `Class[]`, as its second argument. You are only passing it a `Class` argument. Wrap your argument in an array.

```
 tile = ReflectionUtil.getInstance(tileClass, new Class<?>[] {World.class}, world);
```

Comment: Well this is really embarrassing. Sorry :S